# AWS S3 Permissions who is the AWS grantee?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As per the image below who is the AWS grantee?  it seems to always be there by default when you create a bucket.  Does this permission grant rights to the web console? or is it something different?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually your user. From what I remember, you can change that display name by changing your nickname on the AWS support forum:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/username.jspa

Comment: This was driving me crazy... thanks for the tip!! :)

Answer (score 0):

So it is the user or a team. For example if you are in a company account "team-A" and your user name is "person-X", you could do this for example, grant the whole team/account (team-A) permissions to open/download and yourself permissions for everything.